# SEO for possible duplicate content

Tags: 7

Website is about bands and musicians.

Musician can create the profile and add his bio.
Band can create profile and add band members and their bio.
Many musicians are members of several bands, so i will have bio of XY repeated on several pages of my website.

Any idea how to control this since site will be made and controlled more or less by users ?

Comment: How would you solve it for a non-Drupal site?

Comment: I have no idea. I am only using Drupal, and i learned a lot about SEO and am paying a lot of attention to it, my other sites are doing fine on Google. This is first time i have to deal with this as i am not the one who will create content and therefore i can not stop this from happening i guess.

Comment: For the band profile section on a musician's profile page, I'd probably just show a summary of the full profile, then link to the separate band profile page for each - especially if there may be multiple bands for each member profile.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer relies on the way you organize your content. I imagine **bands could be a content type**, with fields like bio, discography, pictures, videos and whatever, and **a field with multiple values** to add users, beeing the band musicians.

The users get their own fields from which bio. Then you can display a list of teasers of musicians in the band node, with a link to complete profile and bio.

EDIT : (for lazy or busy musicians :) I guess NY Big Band staff i.e knows all members's emails, names...

- **Create a role "band manager"** with the rights to create user accounts
- When an account is created by this role, **set up a rule** to send an automatic email to notify the musician,  that an account has been created for him and he's welcome to check if his information is correct.

This way you 'll have a unique "musician content", without SEO duplicate problems, and you 'll also **improve the involvement** of musicians in your website.

Comment: You are about right except the part where band can link to complete musician profile and bio. There will be many cases where bands will create profiles before musician from that band does it and vice versa. Example: New York Big Band has 25 members. Lets say half of band members will create their own profiles, while half don't care and will never do it, or they have it on some other website and won't bother doing it again on

Comment: I edited the answer for that point also.